# regular expression using pandas string match

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

Input data:

```
                        name  Age Zodiac Grade            City  pahun
0                   /extract   30  Aries     A            Aura  a_b_c
1  /abc/236466/touchbar.html   20    Leo    AB      Somerville  c_d_e
2                    Brenda4   25  Virgo     B  Hendersonville    f_g
3     /abc/256476/mouse.html   18  Libra    AA          Gannon  h_i_j
```

I am trying to extract the rows based on the regex on the name column. This regex extracts the numbers which has 6 as length.

```
For example:
/abc/236466/touchbar.html  - 236466
```

Here is the code I have used

```
df=df[df['name'].str.match(r'\d{6}') == True]
```

The above line is not matching at all.

Expected:

```
                         name  Age Zodiac Grade            City  pahun
0  /abc/236466/touchbar.html   20    Leo    AB      Somerville  c_d_e
1     /abc/256476/mouse.html   18  Libra    AA          Gannon  h_i_j
```

Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.match` only searches for a match at the start of the string. Use `str.contains(r'/\d{6}/')` to find entries containing `/` + 6 digits + `/`

Comment: check with .find  or contains?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  It is working with contains. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.match` only searches for a match at the start of the string.

Use  [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a regex like

```
df=df[df['name'].str.contains(r'/\d{6}/')]
```

to find entries containing `/` + 6 digits + `/`.

Or, to make sure you just match 6 digit chunks and not 7+ digit chunks:

```
df=df[df['name'].str.contains(r'(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)')]
```

where

- `(?<!\d)` - makes sure there is no digit on the left
- `\d{6}` - any six digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit on the right is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) instead:

```
df[df['name'].str.contains(r'\d{6,}')]
```